# Form data lost between pages

Tags: php, forms, session

I am struggling to understand the session() command, even after reading numerous pages about it.

I cannot get data from the form to appear on a subsequent page

Here are two very simplified versions of my pages, can someone explain what is missing please

---

"submitform.php" ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Submit Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
header('Location: displayform.php');
}


?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
Email address <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

---

"displayform.php" ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Display Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];

$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

echo "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
echo "Email: " . $email;


?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why do you want to use session there? why not just post from submitForm to displayForm page?

Comment: Turn on `display_errors` and turn up `error_reporting`, always in development.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You ought to be seeing errors - PHP complaining about headers already sent.

Comment: `session_start()` must be called _before any output_. Move the `session_start()` call to the very top of your script, before sending HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a little strange, but I'm guessing it is just to understand sessions so here you go.

As others have said, start the session at the top of each page. Once the form is submitted, store the values in session variables and redirect to the display page. There, you just display the session vars you saved on the first page.

submitform.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
header('Location: displayform.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Submit Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
Email address <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

displayform.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Display Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
echo "Email: " . $email;
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

on 1st page you are setting `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` great.

on page2 you are doing the same thing. There is no `POST['name']` on page 2.  so `$_SESSION['name']` is empty.

just echo `$_SESSION['name']` on page 2 and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You're duplicating `$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];` on the second page. The `POST` data is only available on the page the form submits to... so by the time the user reaches the second the page the values are empty.

Setting empty values to the session is the issue

Comment: Also I believe you need to have session_start() before any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have done few modification in your code as

"submitform.php" ...

```
<?php 
    session_start();// should be top of the page
 if(isset($_POST,$_POST['name'],$_POST['email'])){
    if ($_POST['name']!='' && $_POST['name'] !='')
    {   

      $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
      $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
        header('Location: displayform.php');
     }

 }
```

and "displayform.php" ...

```
 <?php
     session_start();

       $name = $_SESSION['name'];
      $email = $_SESSION['email'];

      echo "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
      echo "Email: " . $email;
  ?>
```

start the session @ the top of the page.

Change the submit form. php file's form tag action as displayform.php.

Answer (score -2):

once the session is set you can just call again that specific session

```
$name = $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
```

once the session is already started at the next page you can just call it

```
//simply like this
echo $name;
```

Comment: This will not work. I think you meant, `echo $_SESSION['name'];` and in the first part you should've mentioned that all of that needs to be wrapped in some code.